# Continue suspend functions from callback

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

I am using firestore as my backend database and saving my data looks like this:

```
suspend fun uploadDataToFirestore() {
  val firestore = Firebase.firestore
  var batch = firestore.batch
 
 -- fill batch with data --

  batch.commit().addOnCompleteListener {
    if (it.isSuccessful) {
      Timber.d("Successfully saved data")
     
      doAdditionalSuspendingStuff()
            
    } else {
      Timber.d("error at saving data: ${it.exception}")     
    }
}
```

The problem lies inside the `onCompleteListener` because I am not able to call additional suspending functions. Is there a way to call suspending functions from within the `onCompleteListener` but so that they are still attached to the same scope because I don't want the function `uploadDataToFirestore` to finish until `doAdditionalSuspendingStuff()` is executed.

Comment: I think you should make the firebase operation synchronous, something like await()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [kotlinx-coroutines-play-services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks#kotlin_coroutine) artifact which contains a small set of utilities for converting between coroutines and Tasks API (which you'll also find common in other Play-related libraries).

You should be able to replace callback-based API (`addOnCompleteListener()`) with suspending `Task.await()` extension function:

```
suspend fun uploadDataToFirestore() {
    val firestore = Firebase.firestore
    val batch = firestore.batch

    try {
        batch.commit().await() // Suspend the coroutine while uploading data.

        Timber.d("Successfully saved data")
        doAdditionalSuspendingStuff()
    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        Timber.d("error at saving data: $exception")     
    }
}
```

`await()` also returns an unwrapped result (the `T` in `Task<T>`).

Under the hood it converts `Task<T>.addCompleteListener()` into a suspending function using [suspendCancellableCoroutine](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/suspend-cancellable-coroutine.html). Source code is available [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services/src/Tasks.kt#L80-L107).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually I was on the way to convert the callback into a suspend function (following this link https://medium.com/swlh/coroutines-tips-and-tricks-callbacks-synchronous-way-to-work-with-asynchronous-code-b9fb840fb793). Then problem is just that the result type I keep getting some runtime error when converting the result of the suspended function into a boolean. If I can't fix that, I will try the library from google play